# Batch Apex not Updating CLOSED__c Checkbox to TRUE

Tags: batch, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch

```
global class BatchApex implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{

    String query = 'SELECT Id,CLOSED__c, Priority FROM Case';

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Case> cas){
        for(Case c : cas){
            if(c.priority=='High'){
                c.CLOSED__c = TRUE;           
            }
        }
        update cas;
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){     
    }    
}
```

Comment: I have few recommendation. Replace dynamic query with static query.  And make query selective: `select Id, Closed__c, Priority from Case where Priority = 'High'`

Comment: @Ishwarya
1º
Do you have any triggers on Case that might be overwriting the update from the Batch?

2º Where are you not getting the expected results, test class? Database after executing the batch?

Comment: Hello Alexander, There is no triggers on case. after executing the class, when i Create a new case or updating the existing case, its not updating CLOSED__c to True.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
global class BatchApex implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{
    List<Case> casToUpdate = new List<Case>();
    String query = 'SELECT Id,CLOSED__c, Priority FROM Case';

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Case> cas){
        for(Case c : cas){
            if(c.priority=='High'){
                c.CLOSED__c = TRUE; 
                casToUpdate .add(c );         
            }

        }
        update casToUpdate ;
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){     
    }    
}
```

---

```
Id batchJobId = Database.executeBatch(new BatchApexs(), 200);
```

It's working for me.Run the above code in the dev console.And copy the code which I have pasted.
In your code you are updating the same list. which is not possible .You need to create another list and update the same